# iOS Recursive Folder and save the files structure into Dictionary&Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion

I'm working on “Folders feature” in my player app, but I have something confused with file recursive. I want to recursive the Document Files then save the folder and files used Dictionary&Array.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)fileRecursive:(NSString *)path{
BOOL isDir;
[_fm fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir];

if (isDir) {
    //Folder
    NSString *folderName = [path lastPathComponent];
    [self.folderArray addObject:folderName];

    NSLog(@"Folder  %@",folderName);
    NSArray *files = [_fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
    for (NSString *file in files) {
        [self fileRecursive:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]];
    }
}else{
    //File
    NSString *fileName = path;
    [self.fileArray addObject:fileName];

    NSLog(@"File %@",fileName);
    }  
}
```

After recursive, I would like to get a Dictionary like this:
[image]

```
dic{ 
"Folder1":[file1,file2];
"Folder2":[file3,file4];
"RootFolder":[file0]; 
}
```

What code I need to add? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem last days, It's weird to use recursion. So just traverse the directory, and record the files and folders, if open the folder, then do that again.